# How to find all the places where variable is used in SSIS package?

Tags: variables, ssis, tracking, bids

I have an SSIS package, it has a user variable, I need to find out in which task and where/how it is used in the package. Does BIDS have any way to track all reference of variables?

We can open .dtsx file  in notepad and can do CTRL-F but we want to avoid looking into so much XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) add-in for your visual studio, it will give you visual feedback on where variables are used. It adds several more good features you may want to try out. It's free!

See the triangle on the bottom right at the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: this add on is good! Is anything available in BIDS to achieve this?

Comment: I had the same problem like you but there really seems to be no way to do it. (Sure, inspecting XML is a way, but you want to avoid that) So as i said - you will be fine by using the add-in!